# LiveUSB can't see HDD

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, hard-drive, dell

I am trying to install 18.04 as a dual boot on a Dell Inspiron 3593 laptop running Windows 10 on a Basic(not Dynamic) partitioned 450GB HDD; have disabled fast startup and secure boot and created space on the disk. The LiveUSB boots up, but it cannot see the HDD. Help urgently needed and gratefully received!

EDIT: In reply to K7AAY ... Unfortunately (?) I have rendered the question obsolete. What I did was change the SATA mode between RAID and AHCI. This meant I could read the hdd from the LiveUSB, but the machine would not boot. Since I was only half-hearted about keeping the Windows system anyway, I wiped the disk and successfully installed 18.04.

Incidentally gparted was unable to reach the hdd, only my 8GB usb being listed.

Comment: Thanks, K7AAY. The type is 'basic'.

Comment: Please run `lsblk && sudo parted -l` in a terminal, copy its output, and add it to the question by clicking [edit]. Also please run gparted and make sure you are looking at /dev/sda (and if not, change the drive to look at by clicking in the button at upper right circled in orange at https://imgur.com/a/ZrrpEC0  ).  Please do not answer with Add Comment; instead, please click [edit].